# How to disable a link button on radio button click in asp.net c# using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

```js
  function disableButtons(val) {
            if (val == 'clear') {
                $('#btnExcellent, #btnFine, #btnBad').prop('disabled', true);
                
                $('#btnSkip').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $('#btnExcellent, #btnFine, #btnBad').removeProp('disabled');
                $('#btnSkip').prop('disabled',true);
            }
        }
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="radioBtnQueryQuality">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radioBtnQueryQuality_0" type="radio" name="radioBtnQueryQuality" value="clear" onclick="disableButtons(&#39;clear&#39;);" /><label for="radioBtnQueryQuality_0">One</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radioBtnQueryQuality_1" type="radio" name="radioBtnQueryQuality" value="notExpNorImp" onclick="disableButtons(&#39;notExpNorImp&#39;);" /><label for="radioBtnQueryQuality_1">Two</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radioBtnQueryQuality_2" type="radio" name="radioBtnQueryQuality" value="invalid" onclick="disableButtons(&#39;invalid&#39;);" /><label for="radioBtnQueryQuality_2">Three</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a id="btnExcellent" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnExcellent&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Excellent</a>
<a id="btnFine" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnFine&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Fine</a>
<a id="btnBad" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnBad&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Bad</a>
<a id="btnSkip" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnSkip&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Skip</a>
```

**REQUIREMENT:**

I want to disable the **btnFour** button when I click the first radio button (i.e. with value **one**).
If I click the remaining two radiobuttons, I want first three Buttons to be disabled except the last one.

It doesn't work the way I want. If I take simple HTML buttons then it works, but it doesn't work in the case of LinkButtons. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code, just pass the value of radio button while calling disable function and make enable or disable of relevant buttons

Code Snippet

```js
function disableButtons(val) {
   if (val == 'clear') {
     $('#btnExcellent, #btnFine, #btnBad').addClass('disabled');
     $('#btnSkip').removeClass('disabled');
   } else {
     $('#btnExcellent, #btnFine, #btnBad').removeClass('disabled');
     $('#btnSkip').addClass('disabled');
   }
   
   $('a.disabled').each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      //console.log('attr = ' + href);
      $(this).data('href', href);
      $(this).attr('href', '#')
   });
   $('a:not(.disabled)').each(function(){
      var href = $(this).data('href');
      //console.log('data = ' + href);
      if(href) {
         $(this).attr('href', href);
      }
   });
}
```

```css
a.disabled {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="radioBtnQueryQuality">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radioBtnQueryQuality_0" type="radio" name="radioBtnQueryQuality" value="clear" onclick="disableButtons(&#39;clear&#39;);" /><label for="radioBtnQueryQuality_0">One</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radioBtnQueryQuality_1" type="radio" name="radioBtnQueryQuality" value="notExpNorImp" onclick="disableButtons(&#39;notExpNorImp&#39;);" /><label for="radioBtnQueryQuality_1">Two</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="radioBtnQueryQuality_2" type="radio" name="radioBtnQueryQuality" value="invalid" onclick="disableButtons(&#39;invalid&#39;);" /><label for="radioBtnQueryQuality_2">Three</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a id="btnExcellent" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnExcellent&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Excellent</a>
<a id="btnFine" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnFine&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Fine</a>
<a id="btnBad" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnBad&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Bad</a>
<a id="btnSkip" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;btnSkip&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Skip</a>
```

Comment: Is there any console error on browser? Can you reproduce this on code snippet

Comment: There is no console error either bro. Let me reproduce this on coded snippet

Comment: you can copy paste the HTML elements from your web page by doing inspect element, there you can get the actual HTML which is converted from ASP code

Comment: Please check the snippet. The ID have been changed as I have literally copy pasted the code.

Comment: use `attr` not `prop` and it is disabled not disable, please check by answer once

Comment: Just now tried it. But still the same result. I used attr and prop both. Nothing happens.

Comment: Do you think The link buttons can be easily found using the technique you provided? I mean is it the correct way? Or do you have any alternative of it?

Comment: Anchor cannot be disable but we can reduce it's opacity to show it disabled and remove href. See my updated answer code snippet

Comment: Perfect! It works like charm. Thank you so much for your patience and help.

Comment: happy to help you :), just put if condition while reading data-href to href as per my updated code, this way there will be no error at all